# C# .net exe running on machine which has visual studio 2010 installed, however it is not responding where only .net 4.0 client profile is installed

Tags: c#, .net

My problem is that my C# .Net executable is running on machine which has Visual Studio 2010 installed, however it is not responding where only .Net 4.0 client profile is installed.

What could be the reason? I've tried with dependency walker but couldn't found anything.

Comment: Is the target of project 4.0?

Comment: What is _"not responding"_?

Comment: @gladiator2345 yes it targets 4.0 client profile only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client profile is a small and in most cases insufficient subset of the .NET runtime. Install the full .NET 4.0 runtime instead.

Answer (score 4):

While all of the other answers are correct, you might take a look on the "my project" page in your solution. There you can find (and eventually change) the used net versions. That is better than trying all net versions...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 4.5 Framework 3.5 and 3.0 frameworks also and see if it works.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Answer (score 0):

That's because that VS2010 has and supports .NET Framework versions (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0). So try to instal all of them and also 4.5 Framework on that machine. Also, what you could do is to see on which Framework version have you made your project and you'll know which one you're machine is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package" on the machine where the executable is not working.